# Chart shows wrong dates at X axis

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, msdn

I am reading date/time and data from a csv file and store this in a line chart. My date/time string is `1-1-2014 21:55:42` or `18-02-2014 00:00:00` which is actually the first entry and i have for a couple of hours data.

First i'm setting the chartArea X axis lablestyle to the proper format: `"d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

Then i parse my actual date string to a DateTime format using the same format as above: `d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss`. And add the data to the chart.

[image]

I ensure you my date is correct:
[image]

And my code:

> private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               string line;
>               char[] delimiters = { ';', ',', '|' };
>
> ```
>         chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
>
>         chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
>
>
>         chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
>
>
>         using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
>         {
>
>             while (!sr.EndOfStream)
>             {
>                 line = sr.ReadLine();
>                 DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime();
>
>                 string[] part = line.Split(delimiters);
>
>                 Console.WriteLine(part[0]);
>
>                 newDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
>                     part[0],
>                     "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
>                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
>                     );
>
>                 chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(newDateTime, part[5]);
>
>             }
>
>         }
>         chart1.Refresh();
>     }
> ```

Comment: What is newdatetime in your code? Is it the correct date? Maybe log that into a file or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You have set the Custom Format for `X-Axis` as  `d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss` but you are just providing the `datetime` without formatting it.

Replace This:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(newDateTime, part[5]);
```

With This:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(
    newDateTime.ToString("d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), part[5]);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Can you elaborate as to why i have to format it again? I already formatted the labelStyle and the newDateTime variable. As i showed it has exactly the same format as i gave it before adding it to my series.